# How to add dropdown menu to inline SwiftUI NavigationBarTitle?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
VStack {
NavigationView {
VStack {
 ...
}.navigationBarTitle("Dropdown Menu", display: .inline)
}
}
```

How can I make it so that a user can 'tap' the "Dropdown Menu" title, a few options in a menu that when selected, will change the title text based on what is selected? Usually for items to the right of the navigationBarTitle, I can do something like:

```
   Text("Hello World!")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                Menu("Add") {
                    Button("File") {}
                    Button("Folder") {}
                }.menuStyle(RedMenu())
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to do this with the title text in the middle with SwiftUI? Or is there some alternative way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (I don't have your menu style but it places menu at title area)

```
.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Menu("Dropdown Menu") {
            Button("File") {}
            Button("Folder") {}
        }.menuStyle(RedMenu())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 16 you can use [.navigationTitle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationtitle(_:)-43srq) together with [.toolbarTitleMenu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbartitlemenu(content:)) to achieve a dropdown menu as long as the `displayMode` is `.inline`.